# Microsoft All in One Media Keyboard Scrolling

Tags: 16.04

So, just finished building an HTPC for the living room and have only one small issue. The keyboard listed above works perfectly, except the two finger scroll on the track pad. Even the media keys elicit a response, which I didn't expect. Running most current version of Ubuntu, windows website shows absolutely zero support/drivers for Linux. Manual says to download the Microsoft software to customize media keys, but seems to indicate the two finger scrolling gesture should work native with the keyboard. Ubuntu settings do not detect a track pad under mouse and keyboard, only settings shown are pointer speed and double click speed. I would really like to stop using a dedicated wireless mouse on my leg, so any and all advice is appreciated. (Even if it is to buy a different, compatible keyboard)
Thanks so much!

Answer (score 1):

I am using ubuntu 17.10 and the two finger scroll worked for me straight out of the box.

I've had this keyboard a mere minutes, but I am very happy with it. I don't think the backlit keys justified the extra money being sought and while the logitech k400 does have pg dn, pg up, home and ins keys, the larger track pad and spill resistance of the Microsoft product persuaded me me to purchase it instead.

As a linux novice I rely on reading forums for help, so I tbought I would reciprocate accordingly with where I could about what is a good product to purchase with a linux system.